# Converting XSD / XJB to Java Classes with JAXB 3.0 and jaxb2-maven-plugin does not work for Annotations (-Xannotate xjc switch)

Tags: java, jaxb, xjc, jakarta-migration

I am trying to migrate my Java class generation from the former javax.* to jakarta.* I am using the Maven Plugin

```
<groupId>org.codehaus.mojo</groupId>
<artifactId>jaxb2-maven-plugin</artifactId>
<version>3.1.0</version>
```

setting the target to 3.0 and using the args

```
<arguments>
    <argument>-Xinject-code</argument>
    <argument>-Xannotate</argument>
</arguments>
```

In my xjb I have some annotate bindings (to add Lombok annotations to my classes).

```
<jxb:bindings version="3.0"
    xmlns:jxb="https://jakarta.ee/xml/ns/jaxb"
    xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema"
    xmlns:xjc="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/jaxb/xjc"
    xmlns:annox="http://annox.dev.java.net"
    jxb:extensionBindingPrefixes="xjc annox">
```

I get the exception: "com.sun.tools.xjc.BadCommandLineException: unrecognized parameter -Xannotate"

I get, that annotate is a xjc plugin. Is there a new implementation of it, that i can add to the jaxb2-maven-plugin dependencies to make this work?

I already tried

```
<plugin>
    <groupId>org.codehaus.mojo</groupId>
    <artifactId>jaxb2-maven-plugin</artifactId>
    <version>3.1.0</version>
    ...
    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.patrodyne.jvnet</groupId>
            <artifactId>hisrc-hyperjaxb-annox-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>2.1.1</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.projectlombok</groupId>
            <artifactId>lombok</artifactId>
            <version>${lombok.version}</version>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>
</plugin>
```

Without success (still unrecognized parameter)

Comment: Replace `xmlns:annox="http://annox.dev.java.net"` with `xmlns:annox="http://jvnet.org/basicjaxb/xjc/annox"`. See also [hisrc-hyperjaxb-annox](https://github.com/patrodyne/hisrc-hyperjaxb-annox#readme)

Answer (score 0):

The `http://annox.dev.java.net` namespace is related to the [jaxb2 annotate plugin](https://github.com/highsource/jaxb2-annotate-plugin)

Now the plugin has been merged into [jaxb-tools](https://github.com/highsource/jaxb-tools) which was former repository of maven-jaxb2-plugin.

You can follow the [migration guide](https://github.com/highsource/jaxb-tools/wiki/JAXB-Tools-Migration-Guide) to get the latest version of the plugin. Starting from v3 (jakarta jaxb3 version), the plugin is located under

```xml
<groupId>org.jvnet.jaxb</groupId>
<artifactId>jaxb-plugin-annotate</artifactId>
<version>[3.0.0 / 4.0.0]</version>
```

Starting from v3, the old `http://annox.dev.java.net` namespace was renamed to `urn:jaxb.jvnet.org:annox` with partial backward support (old namespace is still supported where possible but users are encouraged to move to the new one).